# How to use Rest template for Retrieve Object

Tags: java, resttemplate

I create 2 small micro-services, one is a product service and other one is a catalog service. only the product service deals with the database. Product service is working perfectly with the database. but I cannot access the product Object via the catalog service.

I get the following error:

> Cannot deserialize instance of `Entity.Course` out of START_ARRAY token at [Source:(PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

How can I fix this?

```java
@GetMapping("/catelog")
public Course getCourseObject() {
    
    String CourseUrl="http://localhost:9090/courses";
    
    Course course;
    
    RestTemplate rest=new RestTemplate();
    course =rest.getForObject(CourseUrl, Course.class);
    return  course;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your call returns an array...so

```
return rest.getForObject(CourseUrl, Course[].class);
```

of course also edit the return type from Course to Course[]

Comment: Yes it works.i fixated it . thank you very much for the information. but how i access object?

Comment: What do you mean?